# Include TestNG @Before* steps to allure report

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng, allure

As far as I see, by default Allure shows only steps made is a @Test method.

But my tests have plenty of steps made in @BeforeSuite, @BeforeClass, @BeforeMethod etc. Is there any way to show those steps in allure reports as well? I understand, these steps relate to more than one test, so how can this be done properly?
I use TestNg 6.9.8 and Allure TestNg plugin 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

[Allure 2](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2) supports steps in `@BeforeMethod` / `@AfterMethod`. For other annotations it won't make any sense, as steps belong only to test cases.